# Proving that a quartic extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ does not contain $i$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Let $a\in\mathbb{Q}$ be such that $\pm a$ is not a square of any member in $\mathbb{Q}$. Let $\alpha$ be a complex number such that $\alpha^4=a$.

Prove that $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ does not contain $\mathbb{Q}(i)$.

**My lengthy proof:** Suppose if possible $\mathbb{Q}\subset \mathbb{Q}(i)\subset \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$. The mimimal polynomial $x^4-a$ of $\alpha$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ will factor over $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ as:
$$
x^4-a=(x^2+z_1 x + z_2)(x^2+z_3x+z_4).
$$
Expansion and comparison of coefficients gives:
$$
z_3=-z_1, z_4=z_1^2-z_2, z_1\neq0, z_2=\frac{1}{2}z_1^2, a=z_1^3/2.
$$
From further computations, I arrived at contradiction. Hence $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ is not a subfield of $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$.

**Question:** Is there any clever way to arrive at contradiction, rather than proceeding in school-algebra computations? (I am not applying any technique of Galois theory; I am looking if it is possible without Galois theory.)

Comment: One can use a little bit of theory of formally real fields if $a>0$ and show that $\mathbb{Q} (a) $ is formally real and hence can't contain $i$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$x^4-a$ factors over $\Bbb Q$ as $(x- b)(x-ib)(x+b)(x+ib)$, where $b=\sqrt[4]a$ and $1,i,-1,-i$ are the 4th roots of units. I'd start from there.