# Splitting field of $x^4+2$

Tags: irreducible-polynomials, splitting-field, valuation-theory, dedekind-domain

While learning Galois theory, I tried to construct a splitting field for the polynomial $x^4+2$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, but I am terribly stuck.

Since $x^4+2$ is irreducible by Eisenstein's criterion, I started by setting $K=\mathbb{Q}[y]/(y^4+2)$. Over this field I can factor $x^4+2=(x+y)(x-y)(x^2+y^2)$, but I was not able to find out wether the last factor is irreducible in $K[Y]$ or not.

(Hint: SAGE tells me it is irreducible.)

So I was send on a journey to learn how to find out such things. I was able to figure out the ring of integers of $K$ is $\mathcal{O}_K=\mathbb{Z}[y]/(y^4+2)$ via some trial and error with norms, but don't know how to proceed, mainly because I have trouble determining the prime ideals in $\mathcal{O}_K$, and have yet to gain a better understanding of how this knowledge would help (something valuations and  Newton polygons).

If possible, I would like to avoid proving that $x^2+y^2$ has no zeroes by "brute force", i.e. taking a general element of $K$ and finding a contradiction.
Is there some more constructive way to see this, either geometrically or algebraically?

A reference which describes how to do such things, with examples, would also be very welcome.

Comment: You're overthinking the problem. What are the complex roots of $x^4+2$?

Comment: There is a ridiculous way: if $x^4+2$ splits completely in $K=\Bbb{Q}((-2)^{1/4})$ then $i, \sqrt2$ are in the field, so $K =\Bbb{Q}(i,\sqrt2)$, whence $\Bbb{Q}((-2)^{1/4},\zeta_8)$ is abelian, which implies that $\Bbb{Q}(2^{1/4})$ is abelian, a contradiction because the splitting field of $x^4-2$ irreducible isn't contained in $\Bbb{R}$.

Comment: If you prefer the ring of integers then $(-2)^{1/4}\in \Bbb{F}_{83}$ but $i\not \in \Bbb{F}_{83}$. As $83$ doesn't divide $Disc\, \Bbb{Z}[(-2)^{1/4}]$ this implies that $i\not \in \Bbb{Q}((-2)^{1/4})$.

Comment: Hello @reuns, thanks for your comment. I do have a question though: Do we really need to consider the discriminant? As $\mathbb{F}_{83}$ contains a 4th root of -2, it is a quotient of $\mathcal{O}_K$ (by sending y to that root). In this quotient, (x^2+y^2)  becomes irreducible (since $i\notin \mathbb{F}_{83}$), so it is irreducible over $\mathcal{O}_K$, so it is over K.

Comment: Also, how did you come up with 83? Just so that it contains a 4th root of -2 but not i?

Comment: Yes, I just looked at the prime divisors of $n^4+2$ for small $n$ to find one which is $\equiv 3\bmod 4$. In $\Bbb{Z}[3i]/(3,3i)$ there is no root of $x^2+1$ but there is one in $\Bbb{Z}[i]/(3)$, that's why I use the discriminant to say that $83\nmid [O_K:\Bbb{Z}[(-2)^{1/4}]]$ whence $\Bbb{Z}[(-2)^{1/4}]/(83)\cong O_K/(83)$.

Comment: See related https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4437261/72031

Answer (score 1):

Just fix $\alpha\in \mathbb{C}$ some root of the polynomial. If $u$ is another solution, then $(\frac{u}{\alpha})^4=1$, so $u$ is solution of the equation $t^4-\alpha^4=0$. Then $u\in\{\alpha,-\alpha,\alpha\cdot i, -\alpha\cdot i\}$. So the splitting field is just $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,i)$. As you can see you don't even need to know the explicit form of any root

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but how do you determine the algebraic structure Of this field? Of course a splitting field is always given by adjoining all roots to $\mathbb{Q}$, but I find this not very elucidating, for example if one wants to compute the degree or galois group.

Comment: It's easy to prove that the degree of the extension is 8, so the Galois group has order 8( is a Galois extension) and it's clearly not abelian. Easily you can find two automorphisms of orders 4 and 2, such as their product has order 2. That's the characterization of dihedral group of order 8